# How do you create the ActiveAdmin comments table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I see ActiveAdmin has a feature called comments:
https://activeadmin.info/1-general-configuration.html#comments

I want to play around with this feature.  So I enabled it, ie

```
config.comments = true
config.comments_registration_name = 'ActiveAdminComment'
```

When I restarted my rails server, I got error message:

```
error='ActionView::Template::Error: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "active_admin_comments" does not exist
```

Clearly I need to create a table called `active_admin_comments`.

But how do I create this table?  Can ActiveAdmin generate a migration to create this table?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The [install generator](https://activeadmin.info/0-installation.html#setting-up-active-admin) should create the migration for you.  If you don't have it try re-running the installation, perhaps on a new project.  If you look in the source you will find it in [lib/generators/active_admin/install](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/6038ea6f8fd048926d59ba2c8c29ca2c40d1d41a/lib/generators/active_admin/install/install_generator.rb)

Comment: Yes, it's here: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/6038ea6f8fd048926d59ba2c8c29ca2c40d1d41a/lib/generators/active_admin/install/templates/migrations/create_active_admin_comments.rb.erb  Thank you